# How to place a TextView to the bottom of the screen in java

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview, android-relativelayout

How can I place a TextView to the bottom of the screen? I found some solutions based on xml but nothing when I write code in java.

```
TextView myText = new TextView(this);
myText.setText("some text");
```

In this case, the position is just in the top-left corner.

My XML is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your xml please and tell us where you need it to be placed exactly.

Comment: My xml is almost empty. I don't use xml or graphic layout to place elements by mouse in this application. I don't have any problem with it when I use only buttons (which I generate dynamically throught for loop). I can use AddButtonLayout but I can't find something like that for textView.

Comment: Even if your layout is empty, we need it, because you will still have to reference at least the parent view to add a view to it. Please post it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

//Choose only one of the following.

//Add this if you want your myText be below textView.
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, textView);

//Add this if you want to align your myText to the bottom of the screen.
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

TextView myText= new TextView(this);
myText.setLayoutParams(params);
myText.setText("Some Text");
relativeLayout.addView(myText);
```

where relativeLayout is a the layout you want to add the view to it, so you have to add an id (`android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"`) to that layout, and textView is just another text view in your layout.

If you are going to use a LinearLayout, then no need to `addRule()` to your parameters. It doesn't even have that method as it already aligns the views vertically or horizontally.